# Symbols for left and right limits

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, luatex

I am using lualatex, are there symbols for left and right limits, like small "-" and "+" to put above the numbers? For now I use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{unicode-math}                 

\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{+}} f(x)
\] 
\[
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} f(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

which I feel is not right because the default "+" and "-" are operators and their size and spacing might not be the best for this use.

Comment: Have you considered writing `\lim_{x\downarrow1}` and `\lim_{x\uparrow1}`, respectively? That should make pretty clear that right-hand ("from above") and left-hand ("from below") limits are being taken.

Comment: infix operators like `+` and `-` lose their infix status (and the extra space that implies) if used on their own in this way. What you have is the standard markup.

Comment: Note also that TeX doesn't add spaces around binary operation or relation symbols when used in a superscript or subscript; here the situation is even simpler, as @DavidCarlisle says.

Comment: @Mico thank you, but I prefer to stick with the convention used by my book.

Comment: @egreg and David Carlisle, thank you, I already upvoted your comments,  if one of you answer the question I can accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Infix operators like `+` and `-` lose their infix status (and the extra space that implies) if used on their own in this way. Also as noted by egreg, in a superscript the operators would get no space even used as an infix operator.

What you have is the standard markup.